# When to use enjoy instead of relish?

Tags: word-choice

I did a search on Google and found that the phrase "relish a smoke" is more or less never used, while  "enjoy a smoke" gives me more than 14 million results. I thought "relish" means "enjoy" and thus could be used interchangeably. But apparently not.

What is the difference between relish and enjoy?

Would it be wrong to say "He relished a smoke in the sunny weather"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, `relish` is more intense than `enjoy`

On a one to ten scale, enjoy is anything over five, whereas relish is a seven or higher.

Otherwise they are fairly interchangeable.

Comment: +1 for including a numerical scale. The relative values are "correct" as well (haha).

Comment: Would you say "relish a smoke" is grammatically correct?

Comment: @pilti  Yes, it's fine.